# Facebook SDK 2.0 and Android after June 13, 2013

Tags: android, facebook

Per https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/12/13/facebook-sdk-3-0-for-android-and-native-login/ support for SDK 2.0 on Android will end 6/13/2013.

I believe this means Facebook will no longer provide software updates/bug fixes for SDK 2.0 BUT apps using Facebook SDK 2.0 will still continue to function properly.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you understood correctly:

As written by them in the forum by them :

**The latest version of the SDK is backwards compatible for all apps that have integrated SDK 2.0 or higher. Developers should move to SDK 3.0 by June 13, 2013, at which time we will end support for issues with SDK 2.0.**

These lines clearly suggests that apps using Facebook SDK 2.0 will still continue to function properly.